# Blender white screen on startup

Tags: error, installation, startup-file

I previously had Blender installed through the windows store (which worked ok), but I uninstalled it, intending to get the Steam version and/or the 2.8 beta. I tried both, but when I open either one it just shows a terminal window, then a blank white screen. I also tried the current (2.75b) version from the Blender website, which had the same problem.

My computer is a 64 bit windows 10 laptop with an NVIDIA NVS 4200M GPU (I think).

Can anyone help me find out why this is happening?

Comment: **Never** use the Steam version. It causes more problems than it solves. Try Blender 2.79 instead, but use the zipped version and extract it to your desktop.

Comment: I tried it with the zip version, that doesn't work either. It does the same thing as the others.

Comment: run it from a command prompt and edit your question with any error messages.

Comment: I just updated my graphics card driver manually and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved. It turns out my GPU needed a driver, but it had to be downloaded manually instead of just clicking "update driver".